# Using swift protocols with associated types generically

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a class modelling question with Swift. I have a range of classes that each do the same task (in my example below, Decoding), but they are specialised and each produce a different type of object.

In some cases I will want to be able to talk about my Decoders generally such as `getGeneralInfo()` or `getDecoderForIdentifier()`. In other cases, such as where I am doing a decode operation, I will either instantiate the class directly or use `as?`.

The following code does not work because you can't use `Decoder` as a return type when it has an associated type.

My solution is to remove `decode()` from the protocol and have each class just implement its own. I then need to instantiate concrete classes directly where they are needed. This is workable but it makes me sad.

Is there any way I can rejuggle this to have the compiler enforce "all Decoders should have a `decode()` method according to their associatedtype"?

I have tried using a generic superclass but it requires me to provide a method body for `decode()`, which is pretty gnarly if your return type isn't optional.

```
protocol Decoder {
    associatedtype Model
    func getGeneralInfo() -> GeneralInfo
    func decode(sourceData: Data) -> Model
}

// This return type is not allowed because Decoder has an associated type
func getDecoderForIdentifier(id: String) -> Decoder {
    if id == "mp3" {
        return Mp3Decoder()
    }
    if id == "wave" {
        return WaveDecoder()
    }
    /* ... */
}

class Mp3Decoder: Decoder {
    typealias Model = Mp3Info

    func getGeneralInfo() -> GeneralInfo {
        let info = GeneralInfo()
        /* ... */
        return info
    }

    func decode(sourceData: Data) -> Model {
        let result = Mp3Info()
        /* ... */
        return result
    }
}

class WaveDecoder: Decoder {
    typealias Model = WaveInfo

    /* ... similar to mp3 ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make `Model` a protocol then you can return `Decoder` because then it will not need associated types.

```
protocol Model { 
    // ...
}

protocol Decoder {
    func getGeneralInfo() -> GeneralInfo
    func decode(sourceData: Data) -> Model
}

class Mp3Decoder: Decoder {

    func getGeneralInfo() -> GeneralInfo {
        let info = GeneralInfo()
        // ...
        return info
    }

    func decode(sourceData: Data) -> Model {
        let result = Mp3Info()
        // ...
        return result
    }

}

func getDecoderForIdentifier(id: String) -> Decoder {
    if id == "mp3" {
        return Mp3Decoder()
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah that's clever! I'm yet to convince myself this structure is a good idea but you've definitely solved the biggest issue I'm having, thank you.